# crystal report parameter with yallow icon

Tags: crystal-reports

I have build new crystal report by using command choose from `database expert`
with parameter passed to this query but the parameter show small yellow icon 
and the report not showing any data what that cion means ?

```
SELECT UserList.ID,
       UserList.NUME,
       UserList.NUM,
       UserList.CREATEDON,
       UserList.UPDATEDON,
       UserList.CREATED_DATE
       UserList.UPDATE_DATE
  FROM UserList
WHERE UserList.ID={?P_PatientID}
```

[image: yallow icon]

[image]

Comment: when you hover mouse over yellow icon, what is the message?

Comment: @Siva I wish there were a message

Comment: have you linked parameter in query?

Comment: @Siva it suppose to be linked I followed database expert wizard I put query in it and created the parameter using same wizard and pressed okay the parameter show as i posted and the command with files also in the database fields  ... few second to update my post with the query and new image

Comment: @Siva Please take a look on the post update if you wish

Comment: When you run the query on database the value that you are passing to query is returning any value?

Comment: @Siva yes it return value of course after replacing parameter with the an ID

Comment: What is the datatype in database and datatype you created in crystal reportd

Comment: Is it possible to add a screenshot of the parameter setup and a screenshot of your command while having the parameter edit pop up visible?